# Swift, macos - Can I detect or make other app to be in the foreground?

Tags: swift, macos, swift4

I'm creating an app on macos with Swift,

The app need to open the Safari,
and i need that the Safari app will always be on the foreground.

Can it be done?

Comment: `NSWorkspace` can launch applications and `NSRunningApplication` can activate applications.

Comment: @vadian tnx, i read about NSRunningApplication and found an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @vadian comment, I found the answer

```
func foreground_safari() {
    let apps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
    for app in apps {
        if app.localizedName == "Safari" {
            if !app.isActive {
                app.activate(options: NSApplication.ActivationOptions.activateIgnoringOtherApps)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open safari using a link then try this
`UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string:"http://www.example.com/")! as URL)`

Comment: The question is about macOS and don't use `NSURL` in Swift 3+